# InflateException on a Custom Made PaintView.java

Tags: android, canvas, view, paint

I need help with this error I got from Android Studio. I have an error with the stack trace.

```
02-20 21:52:39.849 1521-1521/com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard, PID: 1521
                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard/com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.TpMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.ui.PaintView
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.ui.PaintView
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
                                                                                                  at com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.TpMainActivity.onCreate(TpMainActivity.java:77)
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
                                                                                                  at com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.TpMainActivity.onCreate(TpMainActivity.java:77) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.TpApplication
                                                                                                  at com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.ui.PaintRunner.<init>(PaintRunner.java:95)
                                                                                                  at com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.ui.PaintView.<init>(PaintView.java:69)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
                                                                                                  at com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.TpMainActivity.onCreate(TpMainActivity.java:77) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am trying to inflate custom `PaintView`. I don't understand the stack trace so I tried everything I saw in other related questions. I'm sorry I don't actually know what I'm doing. I just went ahead and cloned a project from GitHub trying to learn and understand the project while on progress.

I am trying to execute an `Activity`. The stack trace says that the error is at line 77. That would be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_threadpaint);
```

Here is the whole code for the `TpMainActivity.java` which has the said line:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_threadpaint);
        instance = this;

        paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.view_paint_view);
        paintView.setToolButtonAnimator(this);

        buttonColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_color);
        buttonBrush = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_brush);
        buttonMove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_move);
        buttonFill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_fill);
        buttonErase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_erase);
        buttonUndo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_undo);
        buttonRedo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_redo);

        toolButtons = new ArrayList<View>();
        Collections.addAll(toolButtons, buttonColor, buttonBrush, buttonMove, buttonFill, buttonErase, buttonUndo,
                buttonRedo);

        setSelectedBackground(buttonBrush);

        TpPreferencesActivity.addCallbackForPreference(TpMainActivity.this, Preference.LOCKORIENTATION);
        TpPreferencesActivity.addCallbackForPreference(TpMainActivity.this, Preference.MOVETHRESHOLD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.w(TAG, "PaintView destroyed");
        TpPreferencesActivity.removeCallback(TpMainActivity.this);
        paintView.stopPaintThread();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        paintView.saveState(b);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle b) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
        paintView.restoreState(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_save:
            showSaveDialog();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_load:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_LOAD);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_clear:
            paintView.resetCanvas();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_prefs:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, TpPreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Tool Button handler declared in xml.
    public void onToolButtonClicked(View button) {
        switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_tool_color:
            showColorPickerDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_brush:
            if (paintView.selectedTool() == PaintView.Tool.BRUSH) {
                showBrushPickerDialog();
            } else {
                paintView.selectTool(PaintView.Tool.BRUSH);
                setSelectedBackground(buttonBrush);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_move:
            paintView.selectTool(PaintView.Tool.MOVE);
            setSelectedBackground(buttonMove);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_fill:
            paintView.fillWithPaint();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_erase:
            paintView.selectTool(PaintView.Tool.ERASE);
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            setSelectedBackground(buttonErase);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_undo:
            paintView.undo();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_redo:
            paintView.redo();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void setSelectedBackground(Button button) {
        buttonColor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_color);
        buttonBrush.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_brush);
        buttonMove.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_move);
        buttonFill.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_fill);
        buttonErase.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_erase);
        switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_tool_color:
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_color_selected);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_brush:
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_brush_selected);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_move:
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_move_selected);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_fill:
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_fill_selected);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_tool_erase:
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tool_erase_selected);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_LOAD:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                final File imageFile = new File(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
                cursor.close();

                String loadMessge = getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_load);
                final ProgressDialog load = ProgressDialog.show(TpMainActivity.this, "", loadMessge, true);
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bitmap bitmap = Utils.decodeFile(TpMainActivity.this, imageFile);
                        paintView.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        load.dismiss();
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void fadeOutToolButtons() {
        Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_out);
        animateViews(toolButtons, fadeOut);
    }

    @Override
    public void fadeInToolButtons() {
        Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_in);
        animateViews(toolButtons, fadeIn);
    }

    /**
     * Animate all the views with the speciefied animation.
     * 
     * @param views Views to animate
     * @param a Animation to use
     */
    private void animateViews(List<View> views, Animation a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
            a.reset();
            views.get(i).clearAnimation();
            views.get(i).startAnimation(a);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new ColorPickerDialog if necessary and shows it.
     */
    private void showColorPickerDialog() {
        if (colorPickerDialog == null) {
            colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog(this, paintView);
        }
        colorPickerDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new BrushPickerDialog if necessary and shows it.
     */
    private void showBrushPickerDialog() {
        if (brushPickerDialog == null) {
            brushPickerDialog = new BrushPickerDialog(this, paintView);
        }
        brushPickerDialog.show();
    }

    private void showSaveDialog() {
        final SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog(this, paintView.getBitmap());
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void preferenceChanged(SharedPreferences preferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(Preference.LOCKORIENTATION.key())) {
            boolean lock = preferences.getBoolean(key, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "lockScreenOrientation " + lock);
            Utils.lockScreenOrientation(lock, this);
        } else if (key.equals(Preference.MOVETHRESHOLD.key())) {
            float f = 1.0f;
            try {
                f = Float.parseFloat(preferences.getString(key, "1.0f"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR ", e);
                CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.toast_float_parse_error);
                Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "setMoveThreshold " + Float.toString(f));
            paintView.setMoveThreshold(f);
        }
    }
```

Now here's the code for the custom layout for that I am trying to inflate.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.example.lenovo_thinkpad.mobilelectureboard.ui.PaintView
        android:id="@+id/view_paint_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_color"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_color" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_brush"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_tool_color"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_brush" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_move"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_tool_brush"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_move" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_fill"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_tool_move"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_fill" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_erase"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_tool_fill"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_erase" />

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_undo"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_tool_erase"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_undo" />

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn_tool_redo"
        style="@style/ToolButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_tool_undo"
        android:background="@drawable/button_tool_redo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is in `PaintView`. Look at the last `Caused by:` section in the stack trace you've posted.

Comment: @MikeM. I do see that. But I do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: Somewhere in `PaintView` - either in a constructor, or outside of any class method - you're instantiating `PaintRunner`, wherein you're incorrectly casting `android.app.Application` to your `TpApplication` class. We can't really be more specific, as none of the code you've posted is where the issue is.

Comment: @MikeM. I would post my PaintView.class here in the comment. Give me a few minutes.